# Non-Monotonic SQL ID Values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, security

I have been asked to randomize the ID values of all SQL tables, going forward. The reason is so that competitors cannot infer website traffic based on the growth of our ID values.

The default in rails is to use IDs as index, foreign key, and URL paths. These IDs increment linearly.

What is the easiest way to generate pseudo-random integers as IDs for all tables, going forward? Is there a gem I can just toss in?

Note: Rails sometimes has issues with non-integer values, so I would like to stick to integers.

Comment: Hmmm... does rails support using [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)s?  This should have two advantages over random ids - 1) They can monotonically increase, so it plays well with indices (placed at end of table). 2) Unique values, so you don't have to check if the value already exists in the table.  Of course, this is usually larger than an integer.  What sort of data are you worried about leaking to a competitor, customer counts?  What's going to be exposing an internal-only id - there's more than one way to hide this information.

Comment: What about "encrypting" the ID with Blowfish? It means that previous URLs no longer work, oh well. (I'm only *half* joking...)

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much to do with rails as it is that the convention with databases is to use auto increment primary keys.

For new tables, to prevent rails from using this convention you need to tell it not to automatically create the id column, and instead create it yourself.

```
# example of creating a users table

create_table :users, id: false do |t|
  t.integer :id
  # other column definitions
end

add_index :users, [:id], unique: true, name: 'index_id_on_users'
```

Then in your model you will need to set this explicitly before creating the record.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_id

  def set_id
    loop do
      self.id = rand(1<<32)
      break unless User.exists?(self.id)
    end
  end
end
```

The loop is just making sure you get a unique key, otherwise the db constraints will raise an error. There is still a race condition, but if your worried about collisions that much than use something like UUID or SHA.

As for having issues with non integer keys, I've never encountered any issues myself and have used both UUID and SHA keys, as well as using primary keys that were not the id column, that simply requires a little more configuration.

As for your current models, you will have to remove the auto increment from all of your ids, otherwise i'm pretty sure the database will ignore anything you tell it. This apparently can be done by simply issuing a column change migration on id.

```
change_column :users, :id, :integer
```

The caveat here is that your db/schema.rb will not reflect the change, making db:schema:load not generate the right database, though i can say I have never used that rake task to load a database anyway. Just use db:migrate and all should be fine.

And as always, make sure you backup your DB before running a command like this. I just ran it on sqlite3 in my dev environment and it seems to have worked ok.

**Update #1**

An alternate route if all you are concerned with is the URLs is to use a slug instead of the ID. There are some gems out there that will handle this with a little bit of configuration and some new columns. Basically the idea is to have a column used as the url param. So when you use URL helpers instead of outputting /resources/1 it will output /resources/some-url-friendly-slug. This can be something cryptic like a UUID or SHA, or it can be something that is SEO friendly. It depends on if there's something in the model that can be slugged. For example if it was a product_path and the product had a title then the slug could be a url friendly version of the product title, great for SEO.

Comment: Slug eh? I've never heard the term, but I think it describes what I was looking for. I just needed that term. Thanks a lot! Now I can wade through what's out there.

Comment: Here's a list of some good gems that may help. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs